# When I tring to load a https webpage in react native webview it shows blank page

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

When I trying to load a https webpage in react native webview it shows blank page. I tried  to load http it work fine. but i need https for my app. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
   /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {


  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://192.168.0.80/jsxc'}} style={{marginTop: 20}}

      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
       />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

When I tring to load a https webpage in react native webview it shows blank page.

Comment: are you added the Transport Security in your app

Comment: No I cannot add transport security in react native app

Answer (score 1):

Use uri instead of url.

...
source={{uri: this.state.url}}
...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to implement simple webView  component  like below :

```
render(){    
   return (<WebView
            source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
            style={{marginTop: 20}}
        />
)}
```

If it is visible then, there might be problem with **Transport security** in IOS.

But it will work well in Android.

Comment: put some console on onNavigationStateChange, does they appear.

Comment: I put some text to print in the function onNavigationStateChange this function is working, the test show in window. but the webview page not load it show blank page

Comment: Can you provide the url that you want to open in webview, because if all that is working then there might be problem in webpage or transport security of the app.

Comment: webpage has no problem it work fine in browser on android

Comment: How can solve issue of transport security in react native?

Comment: If it is then it must work,  can you check console of navstate in onNavigationState. That can show some error.

Comment: how can check the error console of navstate in onNavigationState?

Comment: navstate provides json consists of current state of webview with additional info.